# PHP file that contains HTML and jQuery has 500 Internal Server Error on AWS Ligtsail Bitnami LAMP

Tags: php, server, bitnami, lampp

I have a website with multiple pages that I uploaded onto the Ligtsail Bitnami LAMP server using FileZilla.

The .HTML pages work fine. The .HTML pages that use jQuery to GET or POST php work fine.

The .php pages that contain HTML or are simply PHP do NOT work at ALL. When I go into inspector to see what is wrong, none of the HTML or JS that is contained in the .php files is shown, instead this is all that is displayed in the inspector:

```
<html>
<head></head> == $0
<body></body> == $0
<html>
```

And the following error is displayed:

```
"filename.php:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"
```

When tested on localhost using XAMPP, all files work. I am new to servers and I hope this is just a newbie issue, let me know if there is any other information I can include.

I checked the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log` and these are my errors:

1. PageSpeed Serf fetch failure rate extremely high; only 1 of 21
   recent fetches fully successful; is fetching working?
2. localhost: server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: if php is not working at all then php is not installed on server.. or there is some misconfiguration in it or in application-server

Comment: Ok, how do I check for whether there is a misconfiguration on the applications server?

Comment: PHP 7 is installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The Bitnami LAMP solution in the Lightsail platform comes with Apache and PHP preconfigured for you to use. From your message, you are getting a 500 error message. I understand there is something wrong in the PHP code you are trying to load and that's why that 500 error occurs. Can you try to create a simple "Hello World" page with PHP in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs folder and see if everything works as expected

```
<?php 
echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; 
?>
```

If you get the Hello World message when accessing yoursite/file.php, that means that PHP is working properly. If you keep getting errors, you can take a look at the Apache's log file (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log) to get more information about them

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/troubleshooting/debug-errors-apache/

Comment: Hello world works perfectly. When it is just php or a php file that is called in a .HTML file everything works. Only if it is a .php file that contains HTML and JS it doesn't work.

Comment: I looked in the error log and these are my errors: PageSpeed Serf fetch failure rate extremely high; only 1 of 21
recent fetches fully successful; is fetching working? AND localh
ost: server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: It seems there is a performance issue in the machine and Pagespeed doesn't work correctly. You can either disable Pagespeed by commenting the pagespeed lines in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file (more info [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/use-pagespeed/#disable-pagespeed)) or increase the instance type (increase the RAM memory of the machine).